# lsp-format-buffer, for C#, Indentation 2

Tags: lsp-mode

What indentation setting does lsp-format-buffer look at?;)

I've tried setting all kinds of variables, but it always indents c# to 4, instead of 2, which I want.

Any pointers?;)

EDIT1:

I'm on onmisharp-roslyn

Here's lsp--formatting-indent-alist

```
lsp--formatting-indent-alist is a variable defined in ‘lsp-mode.el’.

Its value is shown below.

A mapping from ‘major-mode’ to its indent variable.

Value:
((ada-mode . ada-indent)
 (c++-mode . c-basic-offset)
 (c++-ts-mode . c-ts-mode-indent-offset)
 (c-mode . c-basic-offset)
 (c-ts-mode . c-ts-mode-indent-offset)
 (cperl-mode . cperl-indent-level)
 (crystal-mode . crystal-indent-level)
 (csharp-mode . c-basic-offset)
 (csharp-tree-sitter-mode . csharp-tree-sitter-indent-offset)
 (csharp-ts-mode . csharp-ts-mode-indent-offset)
 (css-mode . css-indent-offset)
 (d-mode . c-basic-offset)
 (enh-ruby-mode . enh-ruby-indent-level)
 (erlang-mode . erlang-indent-level)
 (ess-mode . ess-indent-offset)
 (go-ts-mode . go-ts-mode-indent-offset)
 (hack-mode . hack-indent-offset)
 (java-mode . c-basic-offset)
 (java-ts-mode . java-ts-mode-indent-offset)
 (jde-mode . c-basic-offset)
 (js-mode . js-indent-level)
 (js2-mode . js2-basic-offset)
 (js3-mode . js3-indent-level)
 (json-mode . js-indent-level)
 (json-ts-mode . json-ts-mode-indent-offset)
 (lua-mode . lua-indent-level)
 (lua-ts-mode . lua-ts-mode-indent-offset)
 (nxml-mode . nxml-child-indent)
 (objc-mode . c-basic-offset)
 (pascal-mode . pascal-indent-level)
 (perl-mode . perl-indent-level)
 (php-mode . c-basic-offset)
 (powershell-mode . powershell-indent)
 (raku-mode . raku-indent-offset)
 (ruby-mode . ruby-indent-level)
 (rust-mode . rust-indent-offset)
 (rust-ts-mode . rust-ts-mode-indent-offset)
 (rustic-mode . rustic-indent-offset)
 (scala-mode . scala-indent:step)
 (sgml-mode . sgml-basic-offset)
 (sh-mode . sh-basic-offset)
 (toml-ts-mode . toml-ts-mode-indent-offset)
 (typescript-mode . typescript-indent-level)
 (typescript-ts-mode . typescript-ts-mode-indent-offset)
 (yaml-mode . yaml-indent-offset)
 (default . standard-indent))
```

Here's my c-basic-offset

```
c-basic-offset is a variable defined in ‘cc-vars.el’.

Its value is 2
```

Comment: I am following up on what @nega posted. Which server do you use? It seems `csharp-ls` does not yet expose formatting options, while `omnisharp-roslyn` does.

Answer (score 0):

From the [lsp-mode docs](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/main-features/#formatting)

> In general the formatter settings are language server specific(e. g. JDT LS uses eclipse formatter file and lsp-java-format-settings-url to configure it while clangd uses clangd-format and lsp-dart uses the built-in dartfmt from Dart SDK). **The only settings that are controlled on lsp-mode level are indent size and whether the server should use tabs or spaces. Refer to `lsp--formatting-indent-alist` to find out what is the variable that is used for the current major mode.**